# Are there any webcam finger tracking projects?

Tags: webcam

I'm looking for a good piece of free webcam finger (or object) tracking software. I am wondering if there is any, as my searches have been pretty fruitless.

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since I looked at this stuff so I'm not comfortable recommending anything specific, however I seem to remember there being quite a number of available implementations based on [OpenCV's CascadeClassifiers](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/objdetect/cascade_classifier/cascade_classifier.html).

I am not aware of any pre-trained classifiers for fingers specifically: faces and vehicles are much more common targets.